# Is that possible to use several weight of a web font in a email html ? (or 2 different fonts ?)

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-email

I'm building a email on html with the inline css. I need to build it with the google font Open Sans and using the light one with font-weight:300 for the text and the bold one with font-weight: 700 for titles.
I customed on googlefont website the url to have both particularities I needed like that :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

The fact is that my email seems to apply by default the property 700 to all the page and can't find the 300 one if I put in my inline css the font-weight to 300.
However the 300 weight seems to be applied in a text, but I don't know why or understand the logic that could help me to apply a light weight whenever I want.

Does anyone know how if I can use Open Sans bold and light in the same page in a email html?

here is the codepen :

https://codepen.io/Katchou/pen/zzzLOy

Comment: You could create a class with a `font-weight: 300;` rule and then apply that class to the elements you need or apply the rule directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add in your code of how you are using then someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Your code pen is empty..

Comment: sorry, I updated : https://codepen.io/Katchou/pen/zzzLOy

Comment: Please note not alll email clients support web fonts, here is the list: AOL Mail, Native Android mail app (not Gmail app), Apple Mail, iOS Mail, Outlook 2000, Outlook.com app (list is from Dec 2016). You will need proper fallback for non supported browsers **especially Outlook desktop** clients.

Comment: Thank you Syfer fot those precisions, I put defaults web fonts in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this? I can refine my answer if you add more information to the question.

EDIT: 
You added a CodePen. 
I got your title to show as Open Sans Light. 
Check it out! 
https://codepen.io/rickydam/pen/QggBja

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
  @font-face {
     font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
     src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTRa1RVmPjeKy21_GQJaLlJI.woff) format('woff');
  }
</style>

<span>
  <font face="Open Sans">
  Hello world
  </font>
  <br>
  <font face="Open Sans Light">
  Hello world
  </font>
  <br>
  <font face="Open Sans" style="font-weight:700">
  Hello world
  </font>
 </span>
```

Comment: Oh, you want the CSS in the same file. Hold on a sec.

Comment: I've removed the code from the CSS side and moved it into the HTML side.

Comment: It seems to be a good step indeed but now the bold in your code seems to be lighter than expected or light compared to the file I shared. As if only one weight could be applied.

Comment: Keep in mind that font weight is always bold when using h1s. You've gotta undo that. I've updated my CodePen. Tell me what you think @katchou

Comment: You're totally right, the H1 add a bold by it's presence, thank you very much for your help Ricky Dam, you're amazing

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct to help out others with the same problem as you! Keep on coding! :)

Comment: Do email clients that won't download external stylesheets actually download external fonts?

Comment: Well that's the only way I could think of doing it. Do you have any other suggestions for katchou? Cause i'm out of ideas here haha

Comment: @RickyDam It's genuine curiosity, because I see the OP has accepted this answer so I assumed it was working for him.

Comment: Although the OP can always revoke the accept if a better answer comes along or if it turns out the accepted answer doesn't actually work out. I would be thrilled to learn a new way of doing this if it was possible! Gotta keep learning!

Comment: Please note not alll email clients support web fonts, here is the list: AOL Mail, Native Android mail app (not Gmail app), Apple Mail, iOS Mail, Outlook 2000, Outlook.com app (list is from Dec 2016). You will need proper fallback for non supported browsers **especially Outlook desktop** clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different font-weight for the title and content
Refer the snippet

```css
h3{
  font-family:'Open-sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p{
  font-family:'Open-sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<span>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>Content</p>
 </span>
```

Or you can use

```
<span>
  <h3 style="font-family:'Open-sans', sans-serif;font-weight:700">Heading</h3>
  <p style="font-family:'Open-sans', sans-serif;font-weight:300">Content</p>
 </span>
```

Comment: I'm building an html code for a responsive email, your html in that purpose can't have dependencies so your css must be inline. This is probably the only use that the css need to be inline, in all other cases you are right, an external css is always better. https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/

Comment: Team5Studios, katchou asked for inline CSS, which means there can't be any CSS code outside of the HTML file.

Comment: I just mentioned the css without style tags but it is for inline css only he can also use the styling property within p and h tags....